# How do I change the "this" pointer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

I made an object like this:

```
var MyObj = function(arg)
{
  var PublicMethods = { 
          SomeMethod: function(someArg) 
          { 
            if(SomeCheck(arg)
            {
              PublicMethods.SomeFunc2 = somethingElse;
            }
          }
        };

  return PublicMethods;
};
```

However `MyObj` doesn't seem to be persistent and between calls, `PublicMethods` doesnt preserve the new methods added to it, so I tried moving it to global scope, however then it doesn't recognize the '`args`' passed from `MyObj` anymore.

If I make `MyObj` like this:

```
var MyObj = (function()
{
//..
}());
```

Then it becomes a persistent object, but I'm not sure - can I call it like a function again?
`jQuery` seems to have a persistent object and at the same time it can be called like a function, how do they achieve that?

I want to be able to do this:

```
MyObj("Something Here").SomeMethod("Something Else");
```

and thus to be able to create a SomeFunc2 method that I can later call too:

```
MyObj("Something Here").SomeFunc2("Something Else");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply store the result of the initial `MyObj` call in a local variable:

```
var obj = MyObj("Something Here");
obj.SomeMethod("Something Else");
obj.SomeFunc2("Something else");
```

The `PublicMethods` variable is specific to each call of `MyObj`, so when you call `MyObj` for the second time, you get a different instance of `PublicMethods`. By using a variable to store the result of the first `MyObj` call, you can use the same instance of `PublicMethods` for both the `SomeMethod` and `SomeFunc2` functions.

As a side note, you may want to look into [constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function) which would allow you to define functions more simply, instead of returning an object. For example:

```
function Example() {
    this.a = function() {
        return "a";
    };
    this.b = function() {
        this.a = function() {
            return "b";
        }
    }
}

var example = new Example();
example.a(); // => "a"
example.b();
example.a(); // => "b"
```

Comment: So is jQuery a constructor function? I see the jQuery object can be called with an argument and retain its state, as well as to have member variables accessed like a normal object.
This is basically the pattern I'm trying to emulate - the jQuery pattern.

Comment: Kind of. The `jQuery` function is defined as a normal function that returns something. Because everything in JavaScript, even a function, is an object, you can attach custom properties to a function. jQuery uses this to attach a `prototype` object to the `jQuery` function object. By then adding a `constructor` function to the `jQuery.prototype` object, both `jQuery("something")` and `new jQuery("something")` can be used.

Comment: Yeah I think the function instanceof can be used to check if the function is being called normally or by 'new'? Basically you can have 2 different code paths for calling Foo(arg) and new Foo(arg)?

Comment: You don't need to use `instanceof`. Here's an example of how you'd go about doing something similar to jQuery: http://codepen.io/shadowfacts/pen/ObGrNj?editors=0010#0

Comment: Just 1 last thing - if I want to know inside Example if its being called by constructor, I can just pass some boolean when I forward it from the constructor, right?

Comment: Yup, you could either pass an additional argument to the normal function or, if the constructor is going to behave significantly differently, don't forward the the constructor call to the normal function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jQuery method which extends `jQuery` or `jQuery.fn` and can also set `this` context within the method.

```js
(function($) {

  jQuery.addMethod = function addMethod({methodName, method, type}) {
  
    let bool = {
      [type]: false
    };
    
    let _jQuery_jQueryFn_ = Object.keys(bool).pop();
    
    if (type === "jQuery") {
      for (let prop in jQuery) {
        if (prop === methodName 
           || prop.toUpperCase() === methodName.toUpperCase()) {
                bool[type] = true;
                break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (type === "fn") {
      for (let prop in jQuery.fn) {
        if (prop === methodName 
            || prop.toUpperCase() === methodName.toUpperCase()) {
                 bool[type] = true;
                 break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (type === "jQuery" && bool[_jQuery_jQueryFn_] === false) {
      jQuery[methodName] = method;

    }

    if (type === "fn" && bool[_jQuery_jQueryFn_] === false) {
      jQuery[type][methodName] = method;
      
    }
    
    if (bool[_jQuery_jQueryFn_] === true) {
      return Promise.reject(
        new ReferenceError(
          methodName 
          + " previously defined at " 
          + _jQuery_jQueryFn_
      ));
      
    } else {
        console.log(methodName + " defined at " + _jQuery_jQueryFn_);
    }

    return {methodName:methodName, type}; 
  }
})(jQuery);

$(function() {

  Promise.resolve($.addMethod({
      methodName: "add",
      method: function add(a, b, context) {
        console.log(a + b);
        return (context || this)
      },
      type: "jQuery"
    }))
    .then(function({methodName, type}) {
      if (type === "jQuery" && methodName in window[type]) {
          jQuery[methodName](10, 10)
      } else {
        if (methodName in window["jQuery"][type]) {
          jQuery[type][methodName](10, 10);
        }
      }                   
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err)
    });

});

$(function() {

  Promise.resolve($.addMethod({
      methodName: "add",
      method: function add(a, b, context) {
        console.log(a + b);
        return (context || this)
      },
      type: "fn"
    }))
    .then(function({methodName, type}) {
      if (methodName === "jQuery" && methodName in window[type]) {
        jQuery[methodName](10, 10)
      } else {
        if (methodName in window["jQuery"][type]) {
          jQuery("span")[methodName](10, 10);
        }
      }      
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err)
    });

});

$(function() {
  
  
  Promise.resolve(
      $.addMethod({
        methodName: "reverseText",
        method: function reverseText(_text, context) {
          let text = [...(_text || this.text())].reverse().join("");
          (context || this).text(text);
          return (context || this)
        },
        type: "fn"
      }))
    .then(function({methodName, type}) {
      if (type === "jQuery" && methodName in window[type]) {
        jQuery[methodName]()
      } else {
        if (methodName in window["jQuery"][type]) {
          // set context `this` to `span`
          let span = jQuery("section")[methodName]("321", $("span"))    
          .css("color", "sienna");       
          
          console.log(
            span.is(document.querySelector("span"))
          );
        
          jQuery("section")[methodName]()
          .css("color", "green");
        }
      } 
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err)
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<section>section</section>
<span>span</span>
```